# VB.NET Encrypted string not same as original when decrypted, some text missing

Tags: vb.net, encryption, cryptography

I'm doing some server/client coding, and I need to encrypt the data.

I have the following class for encryption and decryption - found some of the code on the net and altered it for my use.

Secure.vb

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text

Public Class Secure
#Region "Encryption Salt"
Private strSalt = "MyTest"
#End Region

#Region "Enum"
Public Enum CryptoAction
    Encrypt = 1
    Decrypt = 2
End Enum
#End Region

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Private Function CreateKey() As Byte()
    Dim strpassword As String = strSalt

    Dim chrData() As Char = strpassword.ToCharArray
    Dim intLength As Integer = chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim bytDataToHash(intLength) As Byte

    For i As Integer = 0 To chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
        bytDataToHash(i) = CByte(Asc(chrData(i)))
    Next

    Dim SHA512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed
    Dim bytResult As Byte() = SHA512.ComputeHash(bytDataToHash)
    Dim bytKey(31) As Byte

    For i As Integer = 0 To 31
        bytKey(i) = bytResult(i)
    Next

    Return bytKey
End Function

Private Function CreateIV() As Byte()
    Dim strPassword As String = strSalt

    Dim chrData() As Char = strPassword.ToCharArray
    Dim intLength As Integer = chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
    Dim bytDataToHash(intLength) As Byte

    For i As Integer = 0 To chrData.GetUpperBound(0)
        bytDataToHash(i) = CByte(Asc(chrData(i)))
    Next

    Dim SHA512 As New System.Security.Cryptography.SHA512Managed
    Dim bytResult As Byte() = SHA512.ComputeHash(bytDataToHash)
    Dim bytIV(15) As Byte

    For i As Integer = 32 To 47
        bytIV(i - 32) = bytResult(i)
    Next

    Return bytIV 'Return the IV.
End Function

Public Function Process(ByVal encString As String, ByVal Direction As CryptoAction, Optional ByVal Encrypted As Boolean = False) As String
    Try
        Dim encBytes() As Byte = Nothing
        If Direction = CryptoAction.Decrypt Then
            encBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(encString)
        Else
            encBytes = New System.Text.UnicodeEncoding().GetBytes(encString)
        End If

        Dim bytBuffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim lngBytesProcessed As Long = 0
        Dim lngStringLength As Long = encBytes.Length
        Dim intBytesInCurrentBlock As Integer = 0
        Dim csCryptoStream As CryptoStream = Nothing
        Dim cspRijndael As New System.Security.Cryptography.RijndaelManaged
        Dim strOutput As String = Nothing
        Dim bytKey() As Byte = CreateKey()
        Dim bytIV() As Byte = CreateIV()
        Dim iStream As New MemoryStream(encBytes)
        Dim oStream As New MemoryStream

        cspRijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros

        Select Case Direction
            Case CryptoAction.Encrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(oStream, _
                                                  cspRijndael.CreateEncryptor(bytKey, bytIV), _
                                                  CryptoStreamMode.Write)

            Case CryptoAction.Decrypt
                csCryptoStream = New CryptoStream(oStream, _
                cspRijndael.CreateDecryptor(bytKey, bytIV), _
                CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        End Select

        While lngBytesProcessed < lngStringLength
            intBytesInCurrentBlock = iStream.Read(bytBuffer, 0, 4096)
            csCryptoStream.Write(bytBuffer, 0, intBytesInCurrentBlock)
            lngBytesProcessed = lngBytesProcessed + _
                                    CLng(intBytesInCurrentBlock)
        End While

        If Direction = CryptoAction.Decrypt Then
            strOutput = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(oStream.ToArray)
        Else
            strOutput = Convert.ToBase64String(oStream.ToArray)
        End If

        csCryptoStream.Close()
        iStream.Close()
        oStream.Close()

        Return strOutput
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
End Class
```

Then when doing the following:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim TestString As String = "<DebugResponse text=""Received Test""/>"

    Console.WriteLine("Original string: " & vbCrLf & TestString & vbCrLf)

    Dim Encrypter As New Secure

    Dim encrypted As String = Encrypter.Process(TestString, Secure.CryptoAction.Encrypt)

    Console.WriteLine("Encrypted string: " & vbCrLf & encrypted & vbCrLf)

    Dim decrypted As String = Encrypter.Process(encrypted, Secure.CryptoAction.Decrypt)

    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted string: " & vbCrLf & decrypted)

    Console.ReadLine()

End Sub
```

the result of the decrypted string would return

```
<DebugResponse text="Received Te
```

Why?
I can't see where the error is :(

Comment: Interesting. I can see that it is only full blocks of 16 bytes but I'm not sure why. It feels like it is something like the streams not being flushed properly but flushing doesn't seem to be helping...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as I suspected in comments that the stream isn't being flushed properly. You need to call `[FlushFinalBlock][1]` after you are done writing to it.

The documentation is not very clear on reasons for this but I would imagine that it is because the encryption is working on 16 byte blocks and it obviously can't encrypt a block until it has all the data. While it has a partial block (as is the case here when you've finished writing) you need to call FlushFinalBlock to tell it that that partial block is in fact the full data.

So in summary put `csCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock` after your while loop that writes to the stream.

Comment: THANK YOU :) That did give me some troubles yesterday - now it works after adding csCryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock after the while loop :)

Comment: Excellent. Glad to have helped. :)